# HttpPost não é resolvido em minha classe na minha aplicação

Tags: android, http, webclient

Não consigo importar classe do `org.apache.http.conn` em meu aplicativo no  Eclipse.

Está é a minha classe:

```
package br.com.cadastro.cadastrocompleto.suporte;

import java.io.IOException;

public class WebClient {

    private String url;

    public WebClient(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void post(String json){
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

            String jsonDeResposta = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
}
```

O que posso fazer a respeito?

**EDIT**

Fica assim no Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Como você faz para importar a biblioteca?

Comment: Vou te mandar um print do que está havendo pra você entender melhor. Eu clico no vermelho para importar e o Eclipse não pode resolver o tipo HttpPost http://imgur.com/vmxm9N0

Comment: Exato! ele pertence a uma [biblioteca](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient423jar.htm) . deve se baixar e adicionar ao projeto!  [Segue como fazer](http://www.henriquelacerda.com.br/2013/04/01/adicionando-bibliotecas-externas-em-projeto-android/)

Comment: Eu baixei no site da Apache Foundation o httpcomponents-client-android-4.3.5.1 mas não consigo achar um arquivo jar com a biblioteca

Comment: ele é um zip? mande o link que baixou! assim fica mais fácil

Comment: @BrunoCésar Deu certo aqui. Eu estava baixando a src, e depois eu baixei o arquivo .bin e veio os arquivos .jar. Obrigado.

Comment: @FelipeDeAquinoNascimento ok, inclui uma resposta para não deixar apenas em comentário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar as bibliotecas de diversas formas. Ela está disponível em repositório público, então se usa [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), pode adicioná-la assim:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient-android</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Caso use [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle), basta declará-la da seguinte forma:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

Caso não use nenhum destes (ou outro) gerenciador de dependências, pode baixar diretamente do [site](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)(código [aqui](http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient-android/)), descompactar e adicionar as bibliotecas no diretório `lib` que forem necessários para o seu caso.

Última alternativa é baixar diretamente de um indexador de dependências, como [MVN Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5.1)